# How to clip area of intersect between two absolutely positioned divs?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two absolutely positioned divs. One over the other. The back one sticks out about 60px from the side of the front one. Both of the divs have semi transparent backgrounds and a rounded top-right corner.

I am trying to make the background of the back div be clipped where ever the front div is covering it.

Can't find a way of doing it.

Sample here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEoNyw

```css
#wrapper {
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1920-1920-3.jpg');
    height: 200px;
}
.block-inner {
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    border-top-right-radius: 40px;
}
#back .block-inner {
    padding-right: 60px;
    background: rgba(0, 101, 164, 0.7);
}
#front .block-inner {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="back">
        <div class="block-inner">
            Back
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="front">
        <div class="block-inner">
            Front
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```